# Waypoints plugin: how do I get current offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
new Waypoint({
    element: $(".foo"),
    handler: function(direction) {
        var offset = this.element.offset().top;
        ...
    },
    offset: 35
});
```

I want to get an element top offset with jQuery. However, this line keeps giving me an error:

```
var offset = this.element.offset().top;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried: `$(this.element).offset().top`???

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this.element)`.

```
new Waypoint({
    element: $(".foo"),
    handler: function(direction) {
        var offset = $(this.element).offset().top;
    },
    offset: 35
});
```